# Error when fetching values via AJAX request in a multi-step form in Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am creating a multi-step page form in a Laravel application whereby I want to carry the values the user entered in the **1st phase of the form** to the **3rd phase of the form through AJAX** (when the user hits submit button on the 2nd phase of the form an AJAX call is triggered and use the values in a final controller). But it aint working.  Please assist?

**First Phase of the form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2c.getplans') }}" class="form-contact"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('FirstName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="{{ old('FirstName') }}" required>
          <label>First Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
           @if ($errors->has('FirstName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('FirstName') }}</strong>
                </span>
            @endif
        </div>

        <div class="form-line{{ $errors->has('MiddleName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
          <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="MiddleName" id="MiddleName"  value="{{ old('MiddleName') }}" required>
          <label>Middle Name *</label>
          <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
          <div class="check-label"></div>
          @if ($errors->has('MiddleName'))
                <span class="help-block">
                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('MiddleName') }}</strong>
                </span>
          @endif
        </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('LastName') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="text-area" class="form-input" id="LastName" name="LastName" value="{{ old('LastName') }}"  required>
      <label>Surname *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('LastName'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('LastName') }}</strong>
        </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line registar love {{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style="margin-left: 0px;">
      <input type="text-area" id="email" class="form-input" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required>
      <label>Email *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
       @if ($errors->has('email'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('phone') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="text-area" class="form-input" name="phone" id="phone" value="{{ old('phone') }}" required>
      <label>Phone Number *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('phone'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('phone') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="date" class="form-input" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required>
      <label>Date of Birth *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>

    <div class="form-line registar move {{ $errors->has('country-residence') ? ' has-error' : '' }}" style='margin-left: 0px;'>
        <select name="country-residence" id="country-residence" class="form-input" required>
            <option selected disabled> </option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value='{{ $country->phonecode }}'> {{ $country->nicename }} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
      <label>Country of Residence *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
      @if ($errors->has('country-residence'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('country-residence') }}</strong>
            </span>
      @endif
    </div>


    <div class="form-line registar move {{ $errors->has('destination-country') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
        <select name="destination-country" id="destination-country" class="form-input" required>
            <option selected disabled> </option>
            @foreach($countries as $country)
                <option value='{{ $country->phonecode }}'> {{ $country->nicename }} </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <label>Country of Destination *</label>
        <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
        <div class="check-label"></div>
        @if ($errors->has('destination-country'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('destination-country') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>


    <button type="submit" class="form-b3c" style="cursor:pointer;"> Get Plans</button>

  </form>
```

**2nd Phase of the form**

```
<!-- Phase 2-->
@extends('B2C::layouts.app')

@section('content')

@if (!empty($plans_benefits))
    <div class="container">
        <div class="PLAN">
            <main class="top">
                <div class="row">
              @foreach ($plans_benefits as $plan_benefits)
                @php
                  $plan_data = $plan_benefits[0];
                  $benefits = $plan_benefits[1];
                  $plan_name = $plan_data->Calculation_TravelPlan->TravelPlan->Name;
                @endphp   
                  <div class="card plan">
                        <h5 class="card-title plan"> {{$plan_name}} </h5>
                            <img class="card-img-top plan" src="{{asset('assets/images-new/superior.svg')}}" alt="Card image cap">
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <div class="travel-plan">
                  <div class="superior-content">
                        <table class="table">
                          <tbody>
                            @foreach($benefits as $benefit)
                                <tr>
                                  <td class="plan-title">{{$benefit->name}}</td>
                                    @if($benefit->value == 'true')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></td>
                                    @elseif ($benefit->value == 'false')
                                        <td class="plan-worth"><i class="fas"></i></td>
                                    @else
                                        <td class="plan-worth"> {{$benefit->value}} </td>
                                    @endif
                                </tr>
                             @endforeach
                           </tbody>
                        </table> 
                  </div>
                </div>
                    <!-- Hiden-->
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"" class ="calc_id" name="calc_id" id="calc_id{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>

                    <input type="hidden" value="{{$plan_name}}" class ="travelplan" name="travelplan" id="plan{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}"/>
                    <!--Hidden-->

                      <p class="card-text plan">TOTAL
                        <span class="amount">$  {{round($plan_data->TravelBasicPremium,2)}} 
                        </span>
                      </p>
                      <!-- AJAX call when the button is hit-->
                       <a id ="{{$plan_data->CalculationId}}" class="plan-quote get_quote" style="cursor:pointer;"><span>Get Quote</span></a>
                    </div>
                     </div>
    @endforeach
      </div>
            </main>
        </div>
  </div>
@endif

@endsection
<!-- END PHASE 2-->
```

**AJAX CODE to fetch values when the button in the above form is hit**

```
            $('.PLAN').on('click', '.get_quote', function () {
                //Fetch inputs from form
                var inputs = $(".form-contact :input");
                var calc_id = $(this).attr('id');
                var c_id = $('#calc_id' + calc_id).val();
                var plan_name = $('#plan' + calc_id).val();
                var entries = inputs.serialize();
                $.ajax({
                    //URL from routes file in Laravel
                    url: 'getquote',
                    //GET request
                    type: 'get',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    data: entries + '&calc_id=' + c_id + '&travelplan=' + plan_name,
                    success: function success(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                        $('.quote').html(response);
                        $tab_active = $progressWizard.find('.active');
                        $tab_active.next().removeClass('disabled');
                        $tab_next = $tab_active.next().find('a[data-toggle="tab"]');
                        triggerClick($tab_next);
                    },
                    error: function error(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                //END AJAX REQUEST
```

**Routes file for get quote**

```
Route::get( '/getquote', 'B2CController@createQuote');
```

**Final controller to use the values fetched via AJAX code**

```
//Get quotes
public
function createQuote(Request $request)
{
    //Optional validation
    $validation = $this->validate($request, [
        'firstname' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'middlename' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'surname' => 'required|string|min:2',
        'country-residence' => 'required',
        'phone' => 'required|string|max:20|regex:/[2547]{4}[0-9]{8}/',
        'destination-country' => 'required',
        'dob' => 'required',
        'departure_date' => 'required',
        'return_date' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
        'calc_id' => 'required',
        'travelplan' => 'required',
        'cover_options' => 'required',
    ]);
    //Using GuzzleHttp to POST values
    $client = new Client();
    $quote = $client->post(route('api.user.createQuote'), [
        'json' => [
            'DobPrincipalTraveller' => $request->dob,
            'TravelStartDate' => $request->departure_date,
            'TravelEndDate' => $request->return_date,
            'CoverOption' => $request->cover_options,
            'WithSpouse' => 0,
            'FirstName' => $request->firstname,
            'MiddleName' => $request->middlename,
            'LastName' => $request->surname,
            'ClientEmail' => $request->email,
            'ContactNumber' => $request->phone,
            'CalculationId' => $request->calc_id,
            'TravelPlan' => $request->travelplan,
        ],
        "http_errors" => false,
    ]);
    $quote_data = json_decode($quote->getBody()->getContents())->data;
    $quoteholder_name = $request->firstname . ' ' . $request->middlename . ' ' . $request->surname;
    $quoteholder_email = $request->email;
    $travel_plan = $request->travelplan;

    $quote_data = view("B2C::travel.quote", compact('quote_data', 'quoteholder_name', 'quoteholder_email', 'travel_plan'))->render();
    return $quote_data;
}
```

Comment: Why not just redirect to a 2nd page?

Comment: @rockhopper72 There are some values on the 1st phase of the form and the 2nd phase I need to pick to use in a controller somewhere else. Thats the purpose of the AJAX code to pick values

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: also, please check out VueJs, it's so much better at handling stuff like this instead of all these jquery selectors

Comment: @wheelmaker Please check the updated question I have added some extra information. Currently the organization I work for doesnt use frameworks for frontend

Comment: @rockhopper72 Kindly check updated question for additional info

Comment: what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `$request->{paramName}` statements to `$request->input('{paramName}')`  like this:

```
...

'DobPrincipalTraveller' => $request->input('dob'),
'TravelStartDate' => $request->input('departure_date'),
'TravelEndDate' => $request->input('return_date'),
'CoverOption' => $request->input('cover_options'),

...
```

Read more about accessing parameters from the request object here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input

Comment: Tried it but it doesnt seem to work,  I think the bug may be in the AJAX code which am finding hard to track down..

Comment: Well that's definitely one of the problems, are you getting any errors? have you tried printing out the request parameters from php to see what's being passed?

Comment: Yah, In the AJAX code, I have tried logging the inputs variable `console.log(inputs)` and it throws validation errors from the validation variable in createQuote function

Comment: Console logging the variable 'inputs' that you've defined in JS is throwing an error from your validation check in PHP ?